# Mootools sortable table

Tags: html-table, mootools, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable mootools table and would like to create one or two header columns unsortable.
How can I do this. My code below:

```
var myTable = new HtmlTable({
    properties: {border: 0,  cellspacing: 0},
    headers: ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4'],
    rows: [],
    zebra: true,
    sortable: true
});

myTable.inject($('column2'));
myTable.sort(0);
```

I would like to sort only 'Column1' and 'Column2'.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set *"table-th-nosort"* class to your table header cell:

```
<th class="table-th-nosort">Not sortable</th>
```

Have a look to **[`HtmlTable.Sort` reference](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/HtmlTable.Sort)** for `classNoSort` option.

Comment: headers: ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', '<th class="table-th-nosort">Column4</th>'] this is not working... Thanks!

Comment: Or where should I place nosort class?